# Can I search a specific webpage in google action console?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to create a google action for the assistant to receive a name from the user and search for it on a specific website https://www.findyello.com/barbados/white-pages/?search=$person_name

I am currently unable to use the SDK and as a result, am using the Google Actions Console. Is there a way to do this solely using the Action Console?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make external API calls, you will need to have an intent that captures the search query and [use a webhook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder) to make an external API call, process the result, and return it to the user.

The code for the webhook would look similar to this:

```js
app.handle('search', async conv => {
    const query = conv.intent.params.['param_name'].original
    const res = await fetch(`https://www.findyello.com/barbados/white-pages/?search=${query}`)
    // Parse res into text
    conv.add(`Here is your first result. ${text}`)
})
```